# Remote login onto server and let someone else see your shell?

Tags: server, remote-access

I remember that I was logged in into my server and my friend connected. Some command let him see my shell and see what I am typing.
What command was that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `screen` command, and its multiuser mode.

**Ctrl-a :multiuser on**    Make the screen session a multi-user session (so other users can attach).
**Ctrl-a :acladd USER**     Allow the user specified (USER) to connect to a multi-user screen session.

http://wiki.networksecuritytoolkit.org/nstwiki/index.php/HowTo_Share_A_Terminal_Session_Using_Screen

http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/

http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Multiuser-Session.html

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the 'ps' command? It will list out what processes are running and can show the processes of other users. I generally run 'ps -ef'

Comment: That only shows what processes are running. Not what is being typed.